# Getting specific user's track list with soundcloud API

Tags: api, soundcloud

Is it possible to get the track list from a specific user via the soundcloud API WITHOUT requiring that specific user to authenticate?

I'm looking for something like the YouTube feeds you can get here: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mrromandiaz/uploads?max-results=10 (I've pointed this at my account, but the username "mrromandiaz" can be replaced with any username to retrieve that user's videos...

Question is, does Soundcloud offer anything similar? I don't need to authenticate, or post, or upload, or control anything... just get user's track lists to show on their profiles, without resorting to the default player.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yep, the API endpoint is at `/users/{user_id}/tracks`. If you don't have the user id, but only their username (permalink), you can use the `/resolve` endpoint to get the user data, including their id.

Documentation here: [user resource](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/users) and here [resolve](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/resolve).

Comment: yes i am trying to access it but it always says unauthorized, can you tell me  how can i get the tracks without being authenticated ?

Comment: @VikasGupta you need to include your client id with each request. this doesn't mean you need to log in, but you need your application's client id.

Comment: @nickf yes i am trying that i even tried http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic&client_id=CLIENT_ID
and i also tried this https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=CLIENT_ID but it says unauthorised every time..
Please help

Comment: @VikasGupta try a valid client id. http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23675/discussion-between-vikas-gupta-and-nickf)

Answer (score 4):

To get the track list from a specific user via the soundcloud API without authenticating:

(javascript example)

```
SC.initialize({
      client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
      redirect_uri: "http://example.com/callback.html",
  });

/**
Once that's done you are all set and ready to call the SoundCloud API. 
**/

/**
Call to the SoundCloud API. 
Retrieves list of tracks, and displays a list with links to the tracks showing 'tracktitle' and 'track duration'
**/

  var userId = 39090345; // user_id of Prutsonic

  SC.get("/tracks", {
      user_id: userId,
      limit: 100
  }, function (tracks) {



      for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
          console.log(tracks[i].title);
      }

  });
```

You can try my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tobiasbeuving/26pHX/5/

(PHP example:)

```
    try {
        $tracks = $client->get('tracks', array('user_id' => '39090345','limit' => 100));
    } catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }
```

(I just answered a similar question [Soundcloud stratus player won't dynamically add more than an individual track at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260692/soundcloud-stratus-player-wont-dynamically-add-more-than-an-individual-track-at/23337734) but I don't know how to handle the 'duplicate question' situation.

Cheers, T