# How to get Specific users , track list using user id

Tags: api, soundcloud

I try to get specific user track list using this but it displays tracks from different users.

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=CLIENT_ID
```

I am also trying `/users/{id}/tracks` but I don't know how to get user `id` from *SoundCloud*?

Comment: FINALLY , I got UserId using this "https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=https%3A//soundcloud.com/userName&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"

Comment: But DOnt Get User Tracks Using this http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/MyuserId.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID but its throwing error pls any one help this {"errors":[{"error_message":"404 - Not Found"}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already answered here: [Getting specific user's track list with soundcloud API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159802/getting-specific-users-track-list-with-soundcloud-api)

In case anyone else wants to know:

you'll have to use `/resolve` as documented in the [Soundcloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve)

`user_hash = @client.get('/resolve', url: 'https://soundcloud.com/{user_id}/')`