# Soundcloud stratus player won't dynamically add more than an individual track at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, soundcloud, soundcloud-stratus

Thanks to other people's questions, I have gotten AJAX links to work for individual songs when clicked in the DOM.  My problem is that I need to find a way to load all of the tracks under a given user's account on soundcloud.  I edited the stratus.js file to make it listen for the click by using .delegate(), but I can't figure out how to call the track listing from soundcloud and load it through the given iframe.  This is the stratus.js file.

```
(function() {
  var $;
  $ = jQuery;
  (function($){var g,d,j=1,a,b=this,f=!1,h="postMessage",e="addEventListener",c,i=b[h]&&!$.browser.opera;$[h]=function(k,l,m){if(!l){return}k=typeof k==="string"?k:$.param(k);m=m||parent;  if(i){m[h](k,l.replace(/([^:]+:\/\/[^\/]+).*/,"$1"))}else{if(l){m.location=l.replace(/#.*$/,"")+"#"+(+new Date)+(j++)+"&"+k}}};$.receiveMessage=c=function(l,m,k){if(i){if(l){a&&c();  a=function(n){if((typeof m==="string"&&n.origin!==m)||($.isFunction(m)&&m(n.origin)===f)){return f}l(n)}}if(b[e]){b[l?e:"removeEventListener"]("message",a,f)}  else{b[l?"attachEvent":"detachEvent"]("onmessage",a)}}else{g&&clearInterval(g);g=null;if(l){k=typeof m==="number"?m:typeof k==="number"?k:100;  g=setInterval(function(){var o=document.location.hash,n=/^#?\d+&/;if(o!==d&&n.test(o)){d=o;l({data:o.replace(n,"")})}},k)}}}})(jQuery);

  $.fn.stratus = function(settings) {
    return $.stratus(settings);
  };
  $.stratus = function(settings) {
    var root_url, src;
    root_url = settings.env === 'development' ? 'http://example.com:3000' : 'http://stratus.sc';
    $('head').append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='" + root_url + "/stratus.css' type='text/css'/>");
    if (settings.align === 'top') {
      $('head').append("<style>#stratus{ top: 0; }</style>");
    }
    if (settings.position === 'absolute') {
      $('head').append("<style>#stratus{ position: absolute; }</style>");
    }
    if (settings.offset) {
      $('head').append("<style>#stratus{ " + settings.align + ": " + settings.offset + "px !important; }</style>");
    }
    $('body').append("<div id='stratus'><iframe allowtransparency='true' frameborder='0' scrolling='0'></div>");
    src = root_url + '/player?' + $.param(settings, true) + '&link=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href);
    $('#stratus iframe').attr({
      src: src
    });
    $('#stratus iframe').load(function() {// /resolve?url=
      return $(this).css({
        visibility: 'visible'
      });
    });
    $('#stratus').show();
    $(document).delegate("a.stratus","click", function () {
      $.postMessage($(this).attr('href'), src, $('#stratus iframe')[0].contentWindow);
      return false;
    });

    return $.receiveMessage(function(e) {
      return $('#stratus').toggleClass('open');
    }, root_url);
  };
}).call(this);
```

I believe that a call through the Soundcloud API will be necessary, then a run through the user data for individual track additions through the iframe. This is the player.js file, which I'm not sure is necessary for this post, but it helped me begin to understand what was happening with the initial adding of tracks from the customisable Links field:

```
console.log("Stratus loading...");
$(function() {
  var b, booleans, getScaledImageData, link, params, scApiUrl, source_origin, strtobool, timecode, _i, _len;
  window.Track = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      var that, track;
      that = this;
      track = this.attributes;
      track.timecode = timecode(track.duration);
      return soundManager.createSound({
        id: "sound_" + track.id,
        multiShot: false,
        url: track.stream_url + (/\?/.test(track.stream_url) ? '&' : '?') + 'consumer_key=' + Stratus.options.key,
        volume: Stratus.options.volume,
        whileplaying: function() {
          Stratus.$('.played').width((this.position / track.duration * 100) + '%');
          return Stratus.$('#player .duration').text(timecode(this.position) + ' / ' + timecode(track.duration));
        },
        whileloading: function() {
          return Stratus.$('.loaded').width((this.bytesLoaded / this.bytesTotal * 100) + '%');
        },
        onplay: function() {
          if (this.loaded) {
            return Stratus.$('.loaded').width('100%');
          }
        },
        onresume: function() {
          if (this.loaded) {
            return Stratus.$('.loaded').width('100%');
          }
        },
        onfinish: function() {
          return Stratus.nextTrack();
        }
      });
    },
    sound: function() {
      return "sound_" + this.id;
    },
    play: function() {
      return soundManager.play(this.sound());
    },
    pause: function() {
      return soundManager.pause(this.sound());
    },
    seek: function(relative) {
      return soundManager.setPosition(this.sound(), this.get('duration') * relative);
    },
    getWave: function(callback) {
      var that;
      that = this;
      return $.getJSON('http://wave64.heroku.com/w?callback=?', {
        url: this.get('waveform_url')
      }, function(data) {
        var waveform;
        waveform = new Image();
        waveform.src = data.data;
        return waveform.onload = function() {
          var waveform_data;
          waveform_data = getScaledImageData(waveform);
          that.set({
            'waveform_data': waveform_data
          });
          return callback();
        };
      });
    },
    comment: function(text) {
      return SC.post("/tracks/" + this.id + "/comments", {
        "comment[body]": text
      }, function() {
        Stratus.$('#comment input').val('');
        Stratus.toggleComment();
        return alert("Comment posted!");
      });
    },
    favorite: function() {
      if (Stratus.$('.love').hasClass('loved')) {
        return SC["delete"]("/me/favorites/" + this.id, function() {
          return Stratus.$('.love').removeClass('loved');
        });
      } else {
        return SC.put("/me/favorites/" + this.id, function() {
          return Stratus.$('.love').addClass('loved');
        });
      }
    },
    isFavorite: function() {
      return SC.get("/me/favorites/" + this.id, function(data) {
        if (!(data.errors != null)) {
          return Stratus.$('.love').addClass('loved');
        }
      });
    }
  });
  window.TrackList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Track,
    select: function(track) {
      this.stop();
      this.current = track;
      return this.trigger('player:select');
    },
    toggle: function(track) {
      if (track && this.current !== track) {
        this.select(track);
      }
      if (this.playing) {
        return this.pause();
      } else {
        return this.play();
      }
    },
    play: function(track) {
      if (track && this.current !== track) {
        this.select(track);
      }
      this.playing = true;
      this.current.play();
      return this.trigger('player:toggle');
    },
    pause: function() {
      this.playing = false;
      this.current.pause();
      return this.trigger('player:toggle');
    },
    stop: function() {
      this.playing = false;
      return soundManager.stopAll();
    },
    prev: function() {
      var i;
      i = this.indexOf(this.current) - 1;
      if (i > -1) {
        return this.at(i);
      } else {
        return this.last();
      }
    },
    next: function() {
      var i;
      i = this.indexOf(this.current) + 1;
      if (i < _.size(this)) {
        return this.at(i);
      } else {
        return this.first();
      }
    },
    random: function() {
      var i;
      i = Math.round(Math.random() * _.size(this));
      return this.at(i);
    }
  });
  window.Tracks = new TrackList();
  window.TrackView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    events: {
      "click": "toggleTrack"
    },
    render: function() {
      return $(this.el).html(ich.track(this.model.toJSON()));
    },
    toggleTrack: function() {
      return Tracks.toggle(this.model);
    }
  });
  window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#stratus'),
    defaults: {
      align: 'bottom',
      animate: 'slide',
      auto_play: false,
      buying: true,
      color: 'F60',
      download: true,
      env: 'production',
      key: 'ybtyKcnlhP3RKXpJ58fg',
      links: ['http://soundcloud.com/qotsa/sets/test'],
      random: false,
      redirect: 'http://stratus.sc/callback.html',
      user: true,
      stats: true,
      volume: 50
    },
    events: {
      "dblclick": "showDrawer",
      "click .prev": "prevTrack",
      "click .toggle": "toggleCurrent",
      "click .next": "nextTrack",
      "click #time": "seekTrack",
      "mousemove #time": "movePosition",
      "click .share": "toggleShare",
      "click .close.sharing": "toggleShare",
      "click .comment": "toggleComment",
      "click .close.commenting": "toggleComment",
      "keypress #add input": "commentTrack",
      "click .love": "favoriteTrack",
      "click #avatar": "logout",
      "click .popup": "popupPlayer"
    },
    initialize: function() {
      var options, that;
      console.log("Stratus initializing...");
      that = this;
      this.options = options = _.extend(this.defaults, this.options);
      Tracks.bind('add', this.add, this);
      Tracks.bind('player:select', this.render, this);
      Tracks.bind('player:toggle', this.toggle, this);
      SC.initialize({
        client_id: options.key,
        redirect_uri: options.redirect
      });
      return SC.whenStreamingReady(function() {
        return that.loadTracks(options.links, function() {
          Tracks.select(options.random ? Tracks.random() : Tracks.first());
          if (options.auto_play) {
            Tracks.play();
          }
          if (options.align === 'top') {
            options.top = true;
          }
          options.color = {
            base: tinycolor(options.color).toHexString(),
            light: tinycolor.lighten(options.color).toHexString(),
            dark: tinycolor.darken(options.color).toHexString()
          };
          $('head').append(ich.theme(options));
          if (SC.isConnected()) {
            that.updateUser();
          }
          return that.animate(function() {
            return that.resize();
          });
        });
      });
    },
    loadTracks: function(links, callback) {
      var index, loadURL;
      index = 0;
      loadURL = function(link) {
        var url;
        console.log("Loading " + link + "...");
        url = scApiUrl(link);
        return SC.get(url, function(data) {
          index += 1;
          if (data.tracks) {
            Tracks.add(data.tracks);
          } else if (data.username || data.creator) {
            links.push(data.uri + '/tracks');
          } else {
            Tracks.add(data);
          }
          if (links[index]) {
            return loadURL(links[index]);
          } else {
            return callback();
          }
        });
      };
      return loadURL(links[index]);
    },
    render: function() {
      var artwork, data, el, that, track;
      that = this;
      track = Tracks.current;
      data = Tracks.current.toJSON();
      el = this.$('#tracks .track_' + data.id);
      this.$('#player .track').html(ich.current(data));
      this.$('#buttons').html(ich.buttons(data));
      this.$('#stats').html(ich.stats(data));
      this.$('#share').html(ich.share(data));
      artwork = data.artwork_url ? data.artwork_url : data.user.avatar_url;
      this.$('#artwork img').attr({
        src: artwork.replace('-large', '-t300x300')
      });
      el.addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
      if (track.has('waveform_data')) {
        this.updateWave(track);
      } else {
        track.getWave(function() {
          return that.updateWave(track);
        });
      }
      if (SC.isConnected()) {
        track.isFavorite();
      }
      return this.resize();
    },
    add: function(track) {
      var view;
      view = new TrackView({
        model: track,
        className: 'track track_' + track.id
      });
      return this.$("#tracks").append(view.render());
    },
    toggle: function() {
      return this.$('#player').toggleClass('playing', Tracks.playing);
    },
    toggleCurrent: function() {
      Tracks.toggle();
      return false;
    },
    prevTrack: function() {
      Tracks.play(Tracks.prev());
      return false;
    },
    nextTrack: function() {
      Tracks.play(Tracks.next());
      return false;
    },
    seekTrack: function(e) {
      var relative;
      if (!Tracks.playing) {
        Tracks.play();
      }
      relative = Math.min(this.$('.loaded').width(), (e.pageX - this.$('#time').offset().left) / this.$('#time').width());
      Tracks.current.seek(relative);
      return false;
    },
    movePosition: function(e) {
      return this.$('.position').css({
        "left": e.pageX - this.$('#time').offset().left
      });
    },
    updateWave: function(track) {
      var canvas, context;
      canvas = this.$('#waveform').get(0);
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.setAttribute('width', 180);
      canvas.setAttribute('height', 40);
      context.clearRect(0, 0, 180, 40);
      return context.putImageData(track.get('waveform_data'), 0, 0);
    },
    animate: function(callback) {
      if (this.options.popup) {
        this.$('#player, #drawer').fadeIn('slow');
      }
      switch (this.options.animate) {
        case 'slide':
          return this.$('#player').slideDown('slow', function() {
            return callback();
          });
        case 'fade':
          return this.$('#player').fadeIn('slow', function() {
            return callback();
          });
        default:
          return this.$('#player').show(0, function() {
            return callback();
          });
      }
    },
    resize: function() {
      this.$('#share').css({
        "margin-right": this.$('#buttons').width() - 30
      });
      return this.$('#comment').css({
        "margin-right": this.$('#buttons').width() - 60
      });
    },
    showDrawer: function() {
      this.$('#drawer').toggle();
      return $.postMessage(true, source_origin, parent);
    },
    popupPlayer: function() {
      Tracks.stop();
      this.toggle();
      return $.popupWindow($.url().attr('source') + '&popup=true', {
        height: 199,
        width: 800,
        location: false
      });
    },
    toggleShare: function() {
      this.$('#share').toggle();
      this.$('#share input').select();
      return false;
    },
    toggleComment: function() {
      var that;
      that = this;
      if (SC.isConnected()) {
        this.$('#comment').toggle();
        this.$('#comment input').select();
      } else {
        this.login(function() {
          return that.toggleComment();
        });
      }
      return false;
    },
    commentTrack: function(e) {
      var text;
      text = this.$('#comment input').val();
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        return Tracks.current.comment(text);
      }
    },
    favoriteTrack: function() {
      if (SC.isConnected()) {
        Tracks.current.favorite();
      } else {
        this.login(function() {
          return Tracks.current.favorite();
        });
      }
      return false;
    },
    login: function(callback) {
      var that;
      that = this;
      return SC.connect(function(user) {
        that.updateUser();
        return callback();
      });
    },
    updateUser: function() {
      var that;
      that = this;
      return SC.get("/me", function(user) {
        return that.$('#avatar').attr({
          src: user.avatar_url
        });
      });
    },
    logout: function() {
      SC.disconnect();
      return alert("Logged out.");
    }
  });
  link = decodeURIComponent($.url().param('link'));
  source_origin = $.url(link).attr('base');
  $.receiveMessage(function(e) {
    var result, url;
    url = e.data;
    result = Tracks.find(function(track) {
      return track.get('permalink_url') === url;
    });
    if (result) {
      return Tracks.toggle(result);
    } else {
      return SC.get("/resolve", {
        url: url
      }, function(track) {
        Tracks.add(track);
        return Tracks.play(Tracks.get(track.id));
      });
    }
  }, source_origin);
  scApiUrl = function(url) {
    if (/api\./.test(url)) {
      return url;
    } else {
      return "/resolve?url=" + url;
    }
  };
  timecode = function(ms) {
    return SC.Helper.millisecondsToHMS(ms);
  };
  strtobool = function(str) {
    switch (str) {
      case 'true':
        return true;
      case true:
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  };
  getScaledImageData = function(image) {
    var color, height, isImageData, lastIndex, orig, origCtx, origImageData, origWidth, populateScaledImagedData, precise, scaleX, scaleY, scaled, scaledCtx, scaledImageData, width, x, y;
    color = Stratus.$('#player').css('background-color');
    color = tinycolor(color).toRgb();
    precise = function(number, precision) {
      precision = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
      return Math.round(number * precision) / precision;
    };
    populateScaledImagedData = function(x, y, srcImageData, indexOffset) {
      var alpha, index, indexScaled, isOpaque;
      indexOffset = indexOffset || 0;
      index = (Math.floor(y / scaleY) * origWidth + Math.floor(x / scaleX)) * 4;
      indexScaled = indexOffset + (y * width + x) * 4;
      alpha = srcImageData.data[index + 3];
      isOpaque = alpha === 255;
      scaledImageData.data[indexScaled] = isOpaque ? color['r'] : 0;
      scaledImageData.data[indexScaled + 1] = isOpaque ? color['g'] : 0;
      scaledImageData.data[indexScaled + 2] = isOpaque ? color['b'] : 0;
      scaledImageData.data[indexScaled + 3] = alpha;
      return indexScaled;
    };
    height = 40;
    width = 180;
    origWidth = image.width;
    scaleX = precise(width / image.width, 4);
    scaleY = precise(height / image.height, 4);
    try {
      isImageData = !(image instanceof Image);
    } catch (e) {
      isImageData = image.hasOwnProperty("data") && image.data.hasOwnProperty("length");
    }
    orig = document.createElement("canvas");
    orig.width = image.width;
    orig.height = image.height;
    origCtx = orig.getContext("2d");
    if (!isImageData) {
      origCtx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    } else {
      origCtx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);
    }
    origImageData = origCtx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    scaled = document.createElement("canvas");
    scaled.width = width;
    scaled.height = height;
    scaledCtx = scaled.getContext("2d");
    scaledImageData = scaledCtx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    y = 0;
    while (y < height) {
      x = 0;
      while (x < width) {
        lastIndex = populateScaledImagedData(x, y, origImageData, 0);
        x++;
      }
      y++;
    }
    return scaledImageData;
  };
  params = $.url().param();
  if (params.links) {
    params.links = decodeURIComponent(params.links);
    params.links = params.links.split(',');
  }
  if (params.redirect) {
    params.redirect = decodeURIComponent(params.redirect);
  }
  booleans = ['auto_play', 'buying', 'download', 'random', 'user', 'stats', 'popup'];
  for (_i = 0, _len = booleans.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    b = booleans[_i];
    if (params[b]) {
      params[b] = strtobool(params[b]);
    }
  }
  return window.Stratus = new AppView(params);
});
```

I'm aware that this is rather intensive, and I apologize for that.  Just throwing up a prayer that I won't have to radically alter my website user's experience in a negative way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the stratus player, but in general - if you want to retrieve a list of tracks of a specific user - given that you know the user's id, you indeed have to make a call to the soundcloud API. You can do it like this:

```
  SC.initialize({
      client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
      redirect_uri: "http://example.com/callback.html",
  });

/**
Once that's done you are all set and ready to call the SoundCloud API. 
**/

/**
Call to the SoundCloud API. 
Retrieves list of tracks, and displays a list with links to the tracks showing 'tracktitle' and 'track duration'
**/

  var userId = 39090345; // user_id of Prutsonic

  SC.get("/tracks", {
      user_id: userId,
      limit: 100
  }, function (tracks) {



      for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
          console.log(tracks[i].title);
      }

  });
```

You can try my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tobiasbeuving/26pHX/5/

Cheers,
T

Comment: I actually just learned a lot, thanks! Unfortunately, there's just too much going on with this plugin for me to sort it all out, as of now I'm probably going to alter the UX for this subsection of the site.  I might be one little step away, but I might be miles from what I need.  One of the many joys of being a relative n00b to js.